# What does bash -i -c do?

Tags: bash, ide

I would like to run ROS using PyCharm, but I have to modify the desktop file `jetbrains-pycharm-ce.desktop` from:

```
Exec="/opt/pycharm-community-4.0.4/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
```

to:

```
Exec=bash -i -c "/opt/pycharm-community-4.0.4/bin/pycharm.sh" %f
```

I wonder what bash -i -c is doing because I do not want to alter PyCharm for future projects.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [`man bash`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/bash.1.html)

```
-i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.

-c command
          command  is  executed in a subshell environment, and its
          output is used as the possible completions.
```

Comment: The second man page quote is for `-C` (capital C). The one for `-c` is the one with: “…commands are read from the first non-option argument command_string.  If there are arguments after…”